# fastest way to anti-join in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

i have two tables. users and accounts.

accounts table :-

```
id  | accountName | userId
--------------------
1   |    natt     |  1
2   |    kelly    |  2
3   |    john     |  3
```

users table :-

```
id  |    username         | 
--------------------
1   |    natt@xyz.com     |
2   |    kelly@xyz.com    |
3   |    john@xyz.com     |
4   |    randy@xyz.com    |
5   |    jamie@xyz.com    |
```

expected output: -

```
userId  |
---------
4       |
5       |
```

as you can see `id` of `users` table act as `foreign key` in `accounts` table.
I want to fetch every user that does not have a `account` associated with it(4,5 in my example). i can do it via `IN or NOT IN` but thats not the fastest way. can some tell me the fastes way to do this? im using postgres.

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: How did you determine that IN/NOT is not fast enough or a faster method exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   SELECT T.ID,T.USERNAME
   FROM USERS  T
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (
      SELECT 1 FROM ACCOUNTS  A WHERE A.USERID=T.ID
   )
```

You can try NOT EXISTS

Comment: is it faster than in and not in?

Comment: Yes, it is at least as efficient as `IN` and often more efficient. Look at the `EXPLAIN` output to see how the database processes the statement.

Comment: okay, just tried this in production db and thank you!! this loaded results really quick!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U.userId FROM users U 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts A ON U.id = A.userId 
 WHERE A.id IS NULL
```